# How to set notepad, or any other program, as the default browser?

Tags: windows-xp

I am interested in setting a standard executable file, such as notepad.exe, as the default Web Browser in Windows XP, SP3. By being the default browser, I mean that the icon of the executable file is listed at the top of the start menu and is associated with .html, .htm, etc files.

I attempted to follow the instructions listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203067(VS.85).aspx) without any success. Any suggestions?

Comment: The default web browser? Notepad isn't a web browser at all, so I don't know how it could be the default for your operating system.

Comment: I realize notepad isn't a browser and can't load webpages, I was just interested in a way to make windows treat it as the default browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set this using regedit.exe:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. You have no idea how much time I have spent trying to do this, only to find that it's a _single_ line in the registry. Hah!  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that Notepad has no concept of connecting to a web server and downloading the page. You'd need an '' application which would purport be the default browser, which would download the re invisible quested file locally and then open it as plain text in Notepad. The app could have whatever icon you like.